# does the main method wait until all the threads are done before executing the next line?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java if I have a class that creates threads from the constructor (by calling some functions of that class) and I create an object of that class in my main method. Does the main method wait until all the threads are done or does it continue to the next line?

for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    WorksWithThreads obj = new WorksWithThreads ( );

    //does something else - does this line happen after all the 9 threads finished their job? 
}

class WorksWithThreads(){
    public WorksWithThreads(){
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            WithThread tread= new WithThread();
    }

    private static class WithThread extends Thread {

        public WithThread () {
            run();
        }

        public void run(){
            //does something
        }
    }

}
```

I hope I was not too confusing.. Thank you in advance.. 
Shiran

Comment: Seems like it'd be fairly easy to test with a sleepy thread and a sysout.

Comment: Your code doesn't start any thread. To start a thread, the start() method must be called. And a thread should NOT be started from its constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually spawn new Threads your main method would continue right after finishing spawning (but before the threads end, assuming they run for sometime)

BUT you are not spawning threads. You are creating instances of the Thread class. To actually spawn new threads you'd have to call start. Calling run() as you do is just a normal method call and processing will only continue after it finished.

You might want to work through the [official tutorial about this topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: Right I forgot about it.. but somehow it worked even without invoking start()... I did something like that from the constructor  .. it was for a parallel quicksort                              if(left<right){
pivot = partition(arr,left,right);
QuickSortThread thread1 = new QuickSortThread(arr,pivot+1,right);
quicksort(arr,left,pivot-1); }                                         I have no idea how it actually sorted my array without invoking start()..

Comment: Well, you called run() which executes your code, it just all runs sequential in the same thread. (judging from the code you posted)

Answer (score 1):

No. The very point of threads is that they don't halt execution of the thread that spawns them. `main()` will continue executing as soon as `WorksWithThreads` has finished spawning all its threads, but the threads it spawns will execute at the same time as the rest of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will run after the 9 threads are created.Here you have not even start those 9 threads.So before they are executed next line in main will be executed